# SSL_read not receiving

Tags: c, sockets, openssl

I'm trying to connect to a secure service via SSL, however in the following code, the `SSL_read` never returns, this is of course normal behaviour if the server does not return any message, the server I am trying to connect to should however return some sort of message. Is there anything not allowing a read in the following?

```
//Initialize SSL library
OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();
//Initialize Crypto algorithms
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

//Create new SSL context accepting SSL V2, V3 or TLS V1.0, V1.1 and V1.2
const SSL_METHOD *method = SSLv23_client_method();
SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
if (ctx == NULL)
{
    printf("Error initializing SSL context.\n");
    return 0;
}
SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
//Create socket descriptor
int sd = 0;
//Create hints for connection
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;//Can be both IPv4 or IPv6
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
struct addrinfo * result;
//Get address info, this could potentially return multiple
int err = getaddrinfo("api.okcoin.com", "9880", &hints, &result);
if (err != 0)
{
    printf("Could not get addr info.\n");
    return 0;
}
//Try connecting to any of the returned addresses
struct addrinfo * res;
for (res = result; res != NULL; res = res->ai_next)
{
    sd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (sd == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not connect to host.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (connect(sd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == 0)
    {
        //Socket is now connected, free addrinfo results
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        //Assign socket descriptor to SSL
        if (SSL_set_fd(ssl, sd) == 0)
        {
            printf("Could not assign socket descriptor.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        //Begin SSL-handshake
        if(SSL_connect(ssl) == 0)
        {
            printf("Could not perform handshake.\n");
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    }
}
//Could not connect socket, free addrinfo results and return error
if (res == NULL)
{
    printf("Could no connect to to any host.\n");
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    return 0;
}
printf("Connected.\n");

SSL_write(ssl, "HELLO\x01", 6);
char * m = malloc(8192);
SSL_read(ssl, m, 8192);
```

Comment: Tell us about the server. Under what conditions does the server send data? Does it just send stuff no matter what? Or is it expected to respond to "HELLO"?

Comment: It is expected to respond to any message (with an error message in this case). I cannot provide a valid input message as it involves security codes.

Comment: @sigvardsen: I suggest that you do a packet capture (i.e. wireshark or similar) to see if there is a data frame from the server as a reply to the data frame send by your client. Both data frames should come after the successful SSL handshake.

Comment: @sigvardsen What is the definition of a "message"? What makes "HELLO" a message that the server will respond to? (How does it know the message isn't "HELLO WORLD" and it just hasn't received all of it yet, so it's waiting for the message?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you are correct, all messages should end with '\x01', however with that added to the message it does still not "read" anything

Comment: @sigvardsen Show us the fixed code. If you show us code that shouldn't work, we can't fix it.

Comment: @sigvardsen: you still only send "HELLO" since you give "5" as the size. Should be "6" to include the \x01.

Comment: @sigvardsen I'm getting the distinct impression that you're not showing us sufficiently real code, making it impossible for us to find the real issue. Given the number of times you've had to change it, and the number of times the thing changed was something that would cause exactly the issue you reported, it seems likely that the problem is just a similar bug to the two we found in the code you won't show us. (Voting to close as not including the code needed to reproduce the problem.)

Comment: I am indeed sorry for the mixup of the "hello" message, however this is the code I have been testing for the last couple of hours. The message I have used contains a password that I cannot share online, therefore I replaced my message with a "dummy"-message. The other parts of the code is thoroughly tested.

Comment: @sigvardsen: again: do a packet capture and you will see if the server replies. If the server is not  responding then there is no need to ask yourself why SSL_read hangs.

Comment: I have tried using Wireshark to capture packets. After the initial handshake, the client sends data to the server and the server responds, however as this is encrypted by SSL I have no clue what the returned message is, or why it is not "read" by the application.

Comment: @sigvardsen Since you won't show me the real code, all I can do is take random guesses about what's wrong with your real code. I'll try another: Are you absolutely, 100% certain beyond any doubt that it's the very first `SSL_read` call for this connection that hangs?

Comment: @David Schwartz This is the code I am using?? You can copy it directly into a main-method and run it (by including appropriate headers: openssl/ssl.h, openssl/err.h, sys/socket.h).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'll happily send you the .c file if needed.

Comment: I can confirm that sending "HELLO\x1" to api.okcoin.com port 9880 gets no response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no error checking, you have no way of knowing whether the `SSL_write()` succeeded, let alone why the `SSL_read()` is blocking. You can't write code like this at any time, let alone when dealing with networks or SSL.

What *I* get with an equivalent Java program is an untrusted server certificate error. When I fix that I get a read timeout after 60 seconds.

I conclude that it isn't your code that's at fault here but the request format.

Comment: If this answer is correct or even useful you should state what the correct request format is, for the benefit of future readers. Otherwise the question is valueless here and should be deleted.